# Change background color according to the data in angular using pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this div

```
<div  *ngFor="let user of userList">
    <div>{{ Name }} </div>
</div>
```

and i have this object

```
 [
        {
            "code": "A",
            "color": "#0071e3"
        },
        {
            "code": "B",
            "name": "#ff0000"
        },
        {
            "code": "C",
            "name": "#249309"
        },
    ..
    ]
```

if Name starts with `A' i have to give same color that is in given object same in the case with other alphabets

Comment: You'll probably want to do that in a directive. Pipes are ment to format/transform data.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Can you pls give some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .html :

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userList">
  <div [style.color]="user.Name | firstLetterBg">{{ user.Name }}</div>
</div>
```

In your pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'firstLetterBg'
})
export class FirstLetterBgPipe implements PipeTransform {

private colors: Array<{code: string, color: string}> = [
    {
      "code": "A",
      "color": "#0071e3"
    },
    {
      "code": "B",
      "color": "#ff0000"
    },
    {
      "code": "C",
      "color": "#249309"
    }
];

  transform(name: string): string {
    const firstLetter = name[0].toUpperCase();
    const colorObject = colors.find(x => x.code === firstLetter);
    return colorObject ? colorObject.color : '';
  }
}
```

But yes according to @MatthieuRiegler, its better to use a directive. You can re use my code to do that.

Regards,